# converting one time zone to another using joda time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

i have made a function to convert from one time zone to another by using joda time but the function is not accepting the date
i have passed the following parameters to this function `"Asia/Kolkata"`, `"UTC"`, `"12-Dec-2014 12:30"`. It is throwing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "12-Dec-2014 12:32" is malformed at "-Dec-2014 12:32"
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:752)
at org.joda.time.convert.StringConverter.getInstantMillis(StringConverter.java:65)
at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:150)
at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:265)
at Dtime.convertTimeZones(Dtime.java:17)
at Dtime.main(Dtime.java:9)
```

Here is the code:

```
public static String convertTimeZones( String fromTimeZoneString, 
    String toTimeZoneString, String fromDateTime) {
         DateTimeZone fromTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(fromTimeZoneString);
         DateTimeZone toTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(toTimeZoneString);
         DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(fromDateTime, fromTimeZone);

         DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = 
             DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm").withZone(toTimeZone);
         return outputFormatter.print(dateTime);
}
```

**DST (day light savings )**
i am passing the parameters  as ("**America/Denver**","**GMT**","**09-Mar-2014 02:00**")on this date the **DST** will start
**for denver**
Sunday, 9 March 2014, 02:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
Sunday, 9 March 2014, 03:00:00 local daylight time instead
but it is throwing the exception
**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse "09-Mar-2014 02:00": Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (America/Denver)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:390)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:849)
    at timeZone.convertTimeZones(timeZone.java:23)
    at timeZone.main(timeZone.java:14)
```

Comment: Can you post part of the stacktrace from the exception?

Comment: @mdewitt please check i have edit it

Comment: fromDateTime needs to be in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. So you want to change it to 2014-12-12 12:30:00.

Comment: i will pass the fromDateTime as (eg 12-Dec-2014) to the function

Comment: is it needs to be only in this format(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm)???

Comment: The following link contains the formats that are accepted by the ISODateFormat.dateTimeParser(): http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser() but you could parse your current formatted date with the answer Elliott Frisch gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your date with an `inputFormatter` (like the `outputFormatter` you've already defined). Something like this

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(
    "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm").withZone(fromTimeZone);
DateTime dateTime = inputFormatter.parseDateTime(fromDateTime);
```

Which I tested, and it outputs

```
12-Dec-2014 07:00
```

Comment: where should i paste these lines?

Comment: i want to know whether this will handle the DST automatic??

Comment: @user2841408 Regarding your question `will handle the DST automatic`: (a) Read the doc, and then test it. (b) Yes. That's the point of calling `withZone`, to adjust the time according to the rules of that time zone.

Comment: @BasilBourque i have test it for "America/Denver" by passing the date as "09-Mar-2014 02:00" on this date time the DST will start,but it is throwing an exception i have include the exception in my question Please refer it and help me.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch what can be the problem how can i handle it?

Comment: Your message is clear. That's not a valid time. Why? Because at the instant it becomes 2 - it is 3. That's why they say "spring forward, fall back".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thats true but how can i handle it ?? if the user inputs this time  then how can i prompt the user to input only the valid time?

Comment: @user2841408 Catch the exception and prompt the user.